# Typescript decorators parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to understand what are the different parameters of a Typescript decorator.

```js
function myDecorator(target) {
  // do something with 'target' ...
}
```

In the example above, I know that target represents the function/class the decorator is attached to, but what are the other parameters of a decorator, their meaning an order, I also would like to get a link to an official documentation specifying this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) But you should also read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ I searched for "typescript decorator" with my search engine and this was the first result. Less than 30 seconds of research effort.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I checked the official documentation in your comment before posting this and I couldn't find the information I'm looking for there.

Comment: _"I couldn't find the information I'm looking for there."_ You should check again. I found it there. Each decorator type has its own list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decorator expects one argument, the target it decorates and some more arguments depending on the type of the target, e.g.

> Method Decorators
>
> The expression for the method decorator will be called as a function
> at runtime, with the following three arguments:
>
> - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
> - The name of the member.
> - The Property Descriptor for the member.

You can find the complete lists on [TypeScript Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) for all decorator types:

- **Class Decorators**

  - Only target class
- **Method Decorators**

  - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member,
  - The name of the member,
  - The Property Descriptor for the member
- **Accessor Decorators**

  - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
  - The name of the member.
  - The Property Descriptor for the member.
- **Property Decorators**

  - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
  - The name of the member.
- **Parameter Decorators**

  - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
  - The name of the member.
  - The ordinal index of the parameter in the function’s parameter list.

Additionally:

> If we want to customize how a decorator is applied to a declaration,
> we can write a decorator factory. A Decorator Factory is simply a
> function that returns the expression that will be called by the
> decorator at runtime.

[[TypeScript Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)]

You can create decorator factories with parameters as you need. They're not limited or specified.

The examples from TypeScript documentation.

Decorator:

```
function sealed(target) {
  // do something with 'target' ...
}
```

applied with

```
@sealed x
```

Decorator factory:

```
function color(value: string) {
  // this is the decorator factory
  return function (target) {
    // this is the decorator
    // do something with 'target' and 'value'...
  };
}
```

applied as

```
@color('blue') x
```

Comment: Why is this in the documentatoin :   return function (
    target,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    console.log("f(): called");
  }; (This is a decorator returned by a decorator factory and it has 3 parameters?

Comment: @Platus I changed my answer. The arguments depend on the type of the target and are listed in the link.